# Why are my DNS query packets are not getting responses?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, dns

I am writing a Java program that sends a DNS Query to a server and I expect to get responses but using Wireshark I am observing that I'm not getting a response for what I believe to be a well-formed packet.

I am comparing my sent packet to a packet sent with `InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com")` and it appears to be exactly the same except for the checksums and packet IDs. Is there an obvious thing I should look for? I can post the packet contents if requested but I'm not sure if there's an easy way to do that.

Edit: Screen cap of packets
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwj5L.png

Comment: Please post the code and packets it generates.

Comment: The destination addresses on your two packets are different.  Perhaps the failing query is not going to the right server?

Comment: @WarrenDew I noticed that as well. I tried manually visiting those ip addresses, the packet that wasn't generating responses gets me to bing.com where the packet that did generate a response didn't take me to a web site. Might have been a DNS server maybe?